# how to calculate FFT and spectrum of acceleration sensor (x,y,z) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, signal-processing

I get acceleration data (x,y,z) captured by smartphone. And I want to calculate FFT and spectrum using python. So, can anyone help me how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Try using numpy. If you have problems, post your attempt and ask specific questions.

Answer (score -2):

The following is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fftpack import fft, ifft, fftfreq
```

load acceleration data

```
df = np.loadtxt('AccelData1.dat')
```

this case I'm using **y** axis

```
N=len(data)
y = data[0:N,1:2]
```

using fftfreq to calculate fft

```
req=fftfreq(N)
```

In this experiment, I want to calculate FFT, spectrum and some filter technique, but I'm confusing how to start FFT using acceleration data (x,y,z) because I'm new in signal processing.